# 'heroku logs' returns 'Response Code 404 (Not Found)'

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm logged into heroku but for some reason when I type:

```
heroku logs
```

...I get the following error message:

```
Response Code 404 (Not Found)
```

Any insight into what might be causing this or how to fix it? As additional info: I have Papertrail installed and sometimes my logs are rather long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an issue on heroku's end: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1249.  Hopefully they'll resolve it soon.

Answer (score 4):

Issue can be resolved by logging in again using

```
heroku login
```